# Can non-residents of Iceland bring alcohol into Iceland?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, iceland, alcohol

I will be flying from the USA and was planning on bringing alcohol. According to this site, http://www.kefairport.is/english/before-departure/customs-regulations/ it seems only locals can bring alcohol into Iceland. Is this correct?

Comment: Where do you that only the locals can bring alcohol into Iceland?

Comment: @Karlson: The section on alcohol is below the heading "Duty-Free luggage of travellers resident in Iceland".  That may explain the OP's interpretation.

Comment: Be aware that the amounts of alcohol on the page you're linking to are also incorrect. I also found an obvious condradiction. According to the site, residents of Iceland are allowed to bring other goods for up to 65.000 ISK without paying taxes, while the value of one item must not exceed 88.000 ISK.

Answer (score 3):

It is a case of bad organization on that page. You are entitled to bring in the same amount of alcohol as residents. For reference see this page on the official Icelandic customs website: http://www.customs.is/default.asp?cat_id=301

Comment: You might want to quote the  relevant parts of the linked page in your answers. Links are prone to 404 oblivion.

Answer (score 3):

It appears Iceland has a flexible import rule -
https://www.tollur.is/english/individuals/customs/traveling-to-iceland/duty-free-imports/alcoholic-beverages-duty-free/
(If the link does not work, search for "Iceland Possible combinations when buying duty free alchohol")
For instance, if you buy NO wine, and NO beer, you would be allowed TWO bottles of scotch.

Answer (score 2):

A quote from the Icelandic customs page: http://www.customs.is/default.asp?cat_id=301:

> - 1 liter spirits and 1 liter wine and 6 liters beer or
> - 3 liters wine and 6 liters beer or
> - 1 liter spirits and 9 liters beer or
> - 1,5 liters wine and 9 liters beer or
> - 12 liters beer
>
> The minimum age for bringing alcoholic beverages into Iceland is 20
>   years and 18 years for tobaccos.
>
> See also information on possible combinations when shopping and video
>   on the Duty Free store website.
>
> Please note that travelers must have the duty free allowance in his or
>   her own possession and present it to the customs authorities if
>   requested. The duty free allowance cannot be assigned to travel
>   agencies, tour guides, bus drivers or others. If a travel agency,
>   driver or tour guide chooses to import goods on behalf of the
>   travellers, the above described allowance for each traveller does not
>   apply  and duties must be paid in accordance with the invoice of the
>   goods. If no invoice can be presented the value of the goods will be
>   assessed by the customs authorities.